# C# Winform panel Shown event

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an event for panel that is equivalent to form event Shown?
I had a few couple of panel switching within a form which will never be closed.
However i couldn't find anything close to an event like Shown which is used in form.
The closes i had is Paint event. However i only wish to update the panel once every time it is shown.

Comment: Form.Shown is raised the very first time the form is displayed. It is never raised again. So, for an arbitrary control, you could use something like HandleCreated, override the OnCreateControl() method to add your code. However, it sounds like you think Form.Shown works a bit differently than it actually does...

Comment: How are you showing the panels? Providing some code would help.

Comment: What's wrong with the focus event? Is it shown out of focus?

Comment: Try if `Layout` does what you want..

Answer (score 0):

You could listen on the `VisibleChanged` event and only act on when visibility = true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You could also experiment with the `Enter` and `Invalidated` events to see if these give you the results you want.

Or if disabling the panel when leaving it is an option, you might be able to use the `EnabledChanged` event in your toolbox.

Comment: The visible is always true in my case. I had a main panel as a container for sub panels, During runtime, the main panel had its control clear and the sub panel added in. The sub panel will not be destroy when unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Shown` is not raised every time the form is shown, rather it [Occurs whenever the form is first displayed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx). This being said, there is no `Panel.Shown` event, and no event which is raised "whenever a panel is first displayed".

You can simulate this behavior with the `Panel.Paint` event, using a flag to keep track of whether it's been "shown" once before. This will make it behave similar to `Form.Shown`.

```
private bool panel1Painted = false;
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!panel1Painted)
    {
        // do your shown stuff here
        panel1Painted = true;
    }
}
```

To keep in the spirit of `Form.Shown`, you may want to reset the flag if the Panel is *reconstructed*. This is not the same as *shown*.

Comment: As the panel itself is not destroy and there could be another instances of the same panel, hence changing panel1 may not reflect subsequently in panel2 of the same instance.

Comment: Use a different flag for each panel. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: @CodyGray "The Paint event gets triggered a *lot*" is an untrue statement (well, depending on your definition of a *lot*, I guess. Once each time the panel is shown, is that a *lot*?). Maybe you could test it and report your findings. Plus `if (!panel1Painted)` is not very costly to evaluate when the Panel is displayed. Maybe you could test this too?

Comment: @CodyGray did you get a chance to test it? Please post your findings